# Sending JSON Data in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

Currently am making a jQuery ajax call to MVC method and sending data from Controller in the below format:

```
["UserInfo ID","User ID"]
```

Controller code:

```
     var autoSuggestlist;
      ........
      .
     return Json(autoSuggestlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Now I want to add another different data like:

```
[ {"editable":true,"edittype":"integer","index":"userInfoId" ]
```

How I can send these 2 different datas in Controller to jQuery Ajax

In the below code

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/GetColumnNamesForGrid",
            data: "",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (result) {
```

result should get me both the above JSON data. How do I need to modify my Controller Code. Please assist

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you mean, but if you want to sent an object with properties from the controller, you can do this:

```
return Json(new { editable = true, edittype = "integer", index = "userInfoId" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Then from javascript, your `result` object can be used as follows:

```
var editable = result.editable;//will be true
```

---

If you are actually wanting to send both data types back at the same time, then create a wrapper object like so:

```
var myObject = new { editable = true, edittype = "integer", index = "userInfoId" };
var myArray = autoSuggestlist;

return Json(new { @myObject = myObject, @myArray = myArray}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Then use in javascript like this:

```
var myObject = result.myObject;
var editable = myObject.editable;//will be true

var myArray = result.myArray;
var firstItem = myArray[0];//will be "UserInfo ID"
```

Comment: i want to send 2 classes at the same time. Is it possible ?

Comment: yes you can. but you need to create ViewModel which hold the Two class data.